# Redirecting HTTPS site to non-www in ASP.NET Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, url-rewriting, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm setting up my first ASP.NET core application. This application runs on HTTPS. Currently, I have two domains that respond: `domain.dk` and `www.domain.dk`, and I want to `301` redirect `www` to `non www`.

I've Googled a lot and ended up adding the following class:

```
public class NonWwwRule : IRule
{
    public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        var req = context.HttpContext.Request;
        var currentHost = req.Host;
        if (currentHost.Host.StartsWith("www."))
        {
            var newHost = new HostString(currentHost.Host.Substring(4), currentHost.Port ?? 80);
            var newUrl = new StringBuilder().Append("https://").Append(newHost).Append(req.PathBase).Append(req.Path).Append(req.QueryString);
            context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(newUrl.ToString());
            context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
        }
    }
}
```

Which I then added to the `Configure` method in my `Startup.cs`:

```
var options = new RewriteOptions();
options.Rules.Add(new NonWwwRule());
app.UseRewriter(options);
```

However, my site still doesn't respond to this and both `www` and without works.

**EDIT:**

I added logging. In my `ApplyRule`, I spammed some logs in:

```
    public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("ApplyRule added");

        var req = context.HttpContext.Request;
        var currentHost = req.Host;

        _logger.LogInformation("Currenthost: " + currentHost.Host + " & URL: " + req.Path);

        if (currentHost.Host.StartsWith("www."))
        {

            _logger.LogInformation("currentHost.Host.StartsWith");

            var newHost = new HostString(currentHost.Host.Substring(4), currentHost.Port ?? 443);
            var newUrl = new StringBuilder().Append("https://").Append(newHost).Append(req.PathBase).Append(req.Path).Append(req.QueryString);
            _logger.LogInformation("newURL: " + newUrl);
            context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(newUrl.ToString());
            _logger.LogInformation("response added: " + newUrl.ToString());
            context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
            _logger.LogInformation("EndResponse added");
        }
    }
```

Reading my logs, I get the impression that it is only called for JS files but not for the main request.

```
2018-03-05 14:44:33.380 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://www.likvido.dk/Content/styles/styles.css?v=RAlju8RYSVrnTxqDUl4Jj9OkakB2USJn8Hg8TkcZ2AY  
2018-03-05 14:44:33.383 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware: Sending file. Request path: '/Content/styles/styles.css'. Physical path: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\Content\styles\styles.css'
2018-03-05 14:44:33.383 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request finished in 2.8044ms 200 text/css
2018-03-05 14:44:33.638 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://www.likvido.dk/Content/images/common/logo-dark.png  
2018-03-05 14:44:33.640 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware: Sending file. Request path: '/Content/images/common/logo-dark.png'. Physical path: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\Content\images\common\logo-dark.png'
2018-03-05 14:44:33.640 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request finished in 2.1224ms 200 image/png
2018-03-05 14:44:33.886 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://www.likvido.dk/js/site.min.js  
2018-03-05 14:44:33.887 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request finished in 0.6345ms 302 
2018-03-05 14:44:34.019 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://www.likvido.dk/Content/images/icons/result.svg  
2018-03-05 14:44:34.021 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware: Sending file. Request path: '/Content/images/icons/result.svg'. Physical path: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\Content\images\icons\result.svg'
2018-03-05 14:44:34.023 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request finished in 4.6392ms 200 image/svg+xml
2018-03-05 14:44:34.175 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://www.likvido.dk/Content/images/icons/customerfocused.svg  
2018-03-05 14:44:34.175 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware: Sending file. Request path: '/Content/images/icons/customerfocused.svg'. Physical path: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\Content\images\icons\customerfocused.svg'
2018-03-05 14:44:34.176 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request finished in 0.9026ms 200 image/svg+xml
2018-03-05 14:44:34.180 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://www.likvido.dk/Content/images/icons/responsible.svg  
2018-03-05 14:44:34.184 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware: Sending file. Request path: '/Content/images/icons/responsible.svg'. Physical path: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\Content\images\icons\responsible.svg'
2018-03-05 14:44:34.185 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request finished in 4.8705ms 200 image/svg+xml
2018-03-05 14:44:34.186 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://likvido.dk/js/site.min.js  
2018-03-05 14:44:34.186 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request finished in 0.527ms 404 
2018-03-05 14:44:34.265 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://www.likvido.dk/Content/images/icons/professional.svg  
2018-03-05 14:44:34.265 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware: Sending file. Request path: '/Content/images/icons/professional.svg'. Physical path: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\Content\images\icons\professional.svg'
2018-03-05 14:44:34.265 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request finished in 0.855ms 200 image/svg+xml
2018-03-05 14:44:33.887 +00:00 [Information] Likvido.Website.Main.Startup: ApplyRule added
2018-03-05 14:44:33.887 +00:00 [Information] Likvido.Website.Main.Startup: Currenthost: www.likvido.dk & URL: /js/site.min.js
2018-03-05 14:44:33.887 +00:00 [Information] Likvido.Website.Main.Startup: currentHost.Host.StartsWith
2018-03-05 14:44:33.887 +00:00 [Information] Likvido.Website.Main.Startup: newURL: https://likvido.dk:443/js/site.min.js
2018-03-05 14:44:33.887 +00:00 [Information] Likvido.Website.Main.Startup: response added: https://likvido.dk:443/js/site.min.js
2018-03-05 14:44:33.887 +00:00 [Information] Likvido.Website.Main.Startup: EndResponse added
2018-03-05 14:44:34.186 +00:00 [Information] Likvido.Website.Main.Startup: ApplyRule added
2018-03-05 14:44:34.186 +00:00 [Information] Likvido.Website.Main.Startup: Currenthost: likvido.dk & URL: /js/site.min.js
2018-03-05 14:44:34.611 +00:00 [Information] Likvido.Website.Main.Startup: ApplyRule added
2018-03-05 14:44:34.611 +00:00 [Information] Likvido.Website.Main.Startup: Currenthost: www.likvido.dk & URL: /js/site.min.js
2018-03-05 14:44:34.611 +00:00 [Information] Likvido.Website.Main.Startup: currentHost.Host.StartsWith
2018-03-05 14:44:34.611 +00:00 [Information] Likvido.Website.Main.Startup: newURL: https://likvido.dk:443/js/site.min.js
2018-03-05 14:44:34.611 +00:00 [Information] Likvido.Website.Main.Startup: response added: https://likvido.dk:443/js/site.min.js
2018-03-05 14:44:34.611 +00:00 [Information] Likvido.Website.Main.Startup: EndResponse added
2018-03-05 14:44:34.714 +00:00 [Information] Likvido.Website.Main.Startup: ApplyRule added
2018-03-05 14:44:34.714 +00:00 [Information] Likvido.Website.Main.Startup: Currenthost: likvido.dk & URL: /js/site.min.js
2018-03-05 14:44:34.478 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://www.likvido.dk/  
2018-03-05 14:44:34.478 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Executing action method Likvido.Website.Main.Controllers.HomeController.Index (Likvido.Website.Main) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
2018-03-05 14:44:34.478 +00:00 [Information] Likvido.Website.Main.Controllers.HomeController: TEST INDEX LOGGER
2018-03-05 14:44:34.479 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewResultExecutor: Executing ViewResult, running view at path /Views/Home/Index.cshtml.
2018-03-05 14:44:34.479 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Executed action Likvido.Website.Main.Controllers.HomeController.Index (Likvido.Website.Main) in 0.9628ms
2018-03-05 14:44:34.481 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request finished in 2.4825ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
2018-03-05 14:44:34.484 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://www.likvido.dk/Content/images/pages/bg-image-2.jpg  
2018-03-05 14:44:34.485 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware: Sending file. Request path: '/Content/images/pages/bg-image-2.jpg'. Physical path: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\Content\images\pages\bg-image-2.jpg'
2018-03-05 14:44:34.486 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://www.likvido.dk/Content/images/icons/phone-icon-3.svg  
2018-03-05 14:44:34.487 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware: Sending file. Request path: '/Content/images/icons/phone-icon-3.svg'. Physical path: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\Content\images\icons\phone-icon-3.svg'
2018-03-05 14:44:34.487 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request finished in 0.9784ms 200 image/svg+xml
2018-03-05 14:44:34.500 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request finished in 16.1968ms 200 image/jpeg
2018-03-05 14:44:34.610 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://www.likvido.dk/js/site.min.js  
2018-03-05 14:44:34.611 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request finished in 1.3489ms 302 
2018-03-05 14:44:34.713 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://likvido.dk/js/site.min.js  
2018-03-05 14:44:34.714 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request finished in 0.573ms 404
```

Comment: I am a bit confused, does your browser redirect when you make a request with the host www.*
or if it redirects does it fail to make a connection. I tried your code and it works fine, www* requests get redirected to non www

Comment: @UmarKarimabadi Thanks for asking so it will be clear. You can see the work at https://likvido.dk and https://www.likvido.dk . It simply doesn't do anything. It is as if the code never ran :-)

Comment: This is really bizarre, app.useRewriter should be the first thing added to your configure method.  The only thing I see wrong in your code is the  currentHost.Port ?? 80. The port for https is 443 of course. You are gonna have to add some logging to see if that rewriter is even hit in the first place

Comment: This should work as-is (I just tested it). @UmarKarimabadi makes a good point about the port though.

Comment: @UmarKarimabadi  - I updated with some logs and updated the post. Same problem. However, I don't understand - it seems that my ApplyRule is only called for a JS file. 
Any idea?

Comment: port 80 is incorrect if you are targeting to https in your first code snippet

Comment: Method `HttpContext.Response.Redirect()` returns 302 http-code by default. You may need to make redirect permanent (301) using bool parameter like this: `context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(newUrl.ToString(), true);`

Comment: I don't think 301 is correct. 307 seems more appropriate 

`context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 307; // Temporary Redirect (since HTTP/1.1)`

`context.HttpContext.Response.Headers["Location"] = text;`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the logs, it looks like you have the middleware the wrong way round

It should be

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            var options = new RewriteOptions();
            options.Rules.Add(new NonWwwRule());
            app.UseRewriter(options);
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

It should be rewriter first, then static, then MVC

Comment: Yes! That worked! Good job :) I will award bounty in 23 hours (forced delay from StackOverflow). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

And for all of you who ware crazy enough to do that in F#:

```ml
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http

type NonWwwRule () =
    interface IRule with
        member __.ApplyRule context =
            let request = context.HttpContext.Request
            let host = request.Host

            if host.Host.StartsWith("www.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) then
                let nonWwwPort = if host.Port.HasValue then host.Port.Value else 443
                let nonWwwHost = HostString(host.Host.Substring 4, nonWwwPort)
                let nonWwwPath = 
                    (sprintf "https://%s%s%s%s" 
                        nonWwwHost.Value
                        request.PathBase.Value 
                        request.Path.Value 
                        request.QueryString.Value)

                context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect nonWwwPath
                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode <- 301

                context.Result <- RuleResult.EndResponse
```

```
let options = RewriteOptions()
options.Rules.Add(NonWwwRule())
app.UseRewriter options |> ignore
```